# Does dart language readAsString change line endings?

Tags: dart

Version: 1.30.0 (system setup)
Commit: c6e592b2b5770e40a98cb9c2715a8ef89aec3d74
Date: 2018-12-11T22:29:11.253Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601

Dart version: 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297 (Thu Nov 8 23:00:07 2018 +0100) on "windows_x64"

I am writing a dart lexical scanner in the dart language. Initialization starts with:

```
File ( filename ).readAsString ( ).then ( ( String contents )
```

On Windows 7, **filename** has line endings of '\r\n'. But **contents** has line endings of '\n'.

Does **readAsString** change line endings?

Comment: No, it doesn't change line endings. There must be some other reason. You could use https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html that splits either line ending format.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look more closely at what I am doing.